# RXJS Subject().mergeMap(funcThatReturnsObservable) returns Observable<any> instead of Subject<any>

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I'm attempting to move a Javascript project to Typescript. Upon changing the extension of the file, I got a bunch of these errors:

```
Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'
```

The Subject is created with:

```
export const foo$ = new Subject().mergeMap(funcThatReturnsObservable)
```

Where funcThatReturnsObservable is:

```
/**
 * Merges data
 * @param {object} data - data used to make observable
*/
function funcThatReturnsObservable(data) {
  return zip(
     // observable,
     // observable,
  )
```

and the subscription happens like this:

```
foo$
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(anotherFuncThatReturnsObsv)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

The location that it's using the next is in the export so that other files can call those events.

```
export default {
  error(error) {
    foo$.next(console.log(error));
  },
}
```

It seems like Typescript isn't able to see that foo$ is still a subject after the mergeMap at the top. I can force it with `as Subject<any>`, but that seems like a code smell. Is there anything I can do to help Typescript see that it will be a Subject? Thanks!

Comment: That's because it's not a subject any more, it IS an Observable.

Comment: @ritaj If subjects are observables, what is it missing after that mergeMap to keep it a subject, then?

Comment: It's missing a lot of things, look at `export declare class Subject<T> extends Observable<T> implements SubscriptionLike` in `rxjs` library and see for yourself.

Comment: Being able to "next" into the end of a pipeline doesn't make much sense. This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @IngoBürk I think you might be right. I added some information on how we're using the "next". Basically we want other files to be able to kick off the error event.

Comment: You need to separate your subject and your piped observable. After the pipe is applied you no longer have a subject that you can call next on